# set text inside ImageSpan android

Tags: android, android-edittext, imagespan

I want to create something like this in `EditText` :

[image: sample image]

It is an `EditText` with `ImageSpans` in between. I created that using `BackgroundColorSpan`. But, I am not able to achieve same effect. I want the spans to behave like "a character". Means, The whole span should be deleted when pressed backspace and when you click on them the cursor should go either in front or in back of the span. I was able to achieve the backspace thing, but not the other one.

So, I tried to use `ImageSpan` they behave as I want them to. But, they don't show the text. 
They only show a colored rectangle. Here is the code I'm using :

```
int start = editText.getText().length();
editText.append(textView.getText());
Spannable spannable = editText.getText();
ColorDrawable background = (ColorDrawable) textview.getBackground();
int colorId = background.getColor();

spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(background), start, editText.getText().length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Here `textView` is a same colored `TextView` with same text. e.g."Day (numeric)" in red background. When user clicks on any of the `textViews`, it will be added in the editText as `ImageSpan` with same text and background color.

Comment: then use a custom `android.text.style.ReplacementSpan`